# Relative Condition Number of $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1/x_2$

Tags: proof-verification, condition-number

Find the relative condition number of $f$. $$f(x_1, x_2)= \frac{x_1}{x_2}$$

---

So, when I use the definition of the relative condition number $\kappa$, I get:

$$\kappa(f,x)= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \sup_{\|\delta x\| \leq \epsilon} \frac{\|f(x+ \delta x) - f(x) \| \cdot \|x\|}{\|\delta x\| \cdot \|f(x)\|} \\
= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \sup_{\|\delta x\| \leq \epsilon} \frac{\|\frac{x_1 + \delta x_1}{x_2 + \delta x_2} - \frac{x_1}{x_2} \| \cdot \|x\|}{|\delta| \| x\| \cdot \|\frac{x_1}{x_2}\|} \\
=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \sup_{\|\delta x\| \leq \epsilon} \frac{\|\frac{x_1 + \delta x_1}{x_2 + \delta x_2} - \frac{x_1 + \delta x_1}{x_2 + \delta x_2} \|}{|\delta| \cdot \|\frac{x_1}{x_2}\|} \\
=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \sup_{\|\delta x\| \leq \epsilon} \frac{\|\frac{0}{x_2 + \delta x_2}\|}{|\delta| \cdot \|\frac{x_1}{x_2}\|} \\
=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \sup_{\|\delta x\| \leq \epsilon} \frac{0}{|\delta| \cdot \|\frac{x_1}{x_2}\|} \rightarrow \infty $$

I don't think this can be right. If anyone could review my calculations, it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: If $f$ is continuously differentiable, which it is for $x_2 \neq 0$ this relative condition number is equal to $$\kappa_{\text{rel}} := \frac{\| f'(x) \| \| x \|}{\| f(x) \|}.$$ Also, this problem is a ill-conditioned one, so the result could be right, I didn't review the actual calculations. If you use the formula above, you get $$\frac{| x_1 |}{ | x_2 |} + \frac{| x_2 |}{ | x_1 |}.$$